# Is it safe to set an account authority to solana system program address

Tags: security

I am letting users create accounts and set a custom authority if they wantfor configuring fields in that account later.

If they don't it defaults to the solana program authority "11111111111111111111111111111111".

Is it safe to leave it like that assuming i don't want anyone to have access to it? or is there any way for someone to get access to the account by signing with that pubkey somehow?

Comment: and why not using "null" ?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that'll be a safe assumption.

You can even have your program treat the system program as a null authority. This is how a lot of programs handle optionality without using any more bytes.

For example, token-2022 uses `OptionalNonZeroPubkey`, where the system program id (the pubkey of all zeros) is treated as `None`: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e4908b929f69f108f978b586bd0cd5b43f24cb1e/libraries/pod/src/optional_keys.rs#L25